# MVC bundle alterando Content do css - Font Awesome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, font-awesome, bundle

Estou com um problema com o *bundle* do ASP.NET MVC. Quando rodo a aplicação local, os ícones do FontAwesome são renderizados perfeitamente. Inclusive quando habilito o *bundle* local.

Porém, quando publico a aplicação no servidor, o bundle altera todos os "content" do css do font awesome para "?" e os ícones somem.

Não acredito que deva ser nada da aplicação, pois no iisexpress roda normalmente.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/style").Include(
                "~/Content/poppins.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
                "~/Content/animate.css",
                "~/Content/filter.css",
                "~/Content/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-select.css",
                "~/Content/jquery.dataTables.css",
                "~/Content/multi-select.css",
                "~/Content/sweetalert.css",
                "~/Content/jstree.css",
                "~/Content/dataTables.select.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-tagsinput.css",
                "~/Content/style.css"
        ));
```

Imagens

Ícones errados (prod)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ícones certos (localhost)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todos os content das classes do font-awesome aparecem como (um exemplo), mas só depois do bundle, pq o arquivo de css está correto:

```
.fa-user {    
    content: '?';
}
```

Comment: Eu tive um problema parecido faz uns dias, mas eu não consigo lembrar o que causava isto.

Comment: Qual é pasta (estrutura completa com base na raiz da aplicação) onde se encontra o arquivo do Font Awesome?

Comment: /Content/font-awesome.min.css e as fontes estão em /fonts/fontaewsome...

Comment: Posta por favor o arquvo BundleConfig.cs

Comment: Editei com o bundle dos css. Já tentei alterar a ordem e deixar o font-awesome por último, mas também não resolveu.

Comment: Claudio, o problema aí é com os caminhos. Tudo o que for "bundlerizado" vai acabar ficando em `bundles/style`, provavelmente o CSS do FA está usando os caminhos relativos considerando a estrutura em que ele esteja no Content e por isso acaba não achando o arquivo de fontes. Você instalou o FA pelo Nuget?

Comment: Sim, instalei pelo nuget. E isso não faz sentido, pois a referência dos arquivos de fonte, no font-awesome, está como ../fonts, logo, estando em /Content ou /bundles, é apenas 1 nível abaixo da raíz.

Comment: Bem, eu não tenho como adivinhar a estrutura das pastas. Você tem como confirmar que a pasta `fonts` está acessível para requisições externas?

Answer (score 0):

Colocou o meta na header?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

ou

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Sim, tem a tag meta com o charset. Já tentei, também, @charset dentro do CSS

Comment: teu path ta correto, tem o meta, tem como mander o link do site para eu olhar?

Comment: Não consigo, pois é preciso fazer login e essa aplicação está rodando em produção.

Comment: entao posta o erro do console

Comment: Não aparece nenhum erro de CSS no console.

Comment: entao abre o console vai para o Network e da um refresh na pagina, ver se tem algum status diferente de 200